# How can I get the currently viewed product ID within a javascript <script>?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, javascript, simple-product

I'm trying to get the currently viewed product ID (simple products) within a javascript  tag. Anybody know whether this is possible?

This is the syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    window._pa = window._pa || {};
    _pa.productId = "PRODUCT ID";

more code
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I am assuming that this code is being placed in a template file. If this is not the case then I am sorry for the miss understanding.

The quickest way to get the currently viewed product id is to load the product from the registry. The following code should get you the information that you need.

```
Mage::registry('product')->getId()
```

Though if the block being used to show this template extends the core `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` then you can simply call:

```
$this->getProduct()->getId()
```

Or if this is simply in JavaScript and not in a template you could read the value from the hidden element named "product" that is in the standard add to cart form on the product page.

```
<form id="product_addtocart_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="product_id">
</form>
```